# BMI 1.1.1.4 URL prefix

Tags: apache

From time to time my websites does not show images. When you look at their URL it looks like this:

```
http://1.1.1.4/bmi/www.domain.com/path/to/image.png
```

The www.domain.com/path/to/image.png is a valid path.

What is the problem? I use Apache, WSGI and Django.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the page source is being mangled by Vodafone. This answer may be related:

[Stop mobile network proxy from injecting JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113268/how-to-stop-javascript-injection-from-vodafone-proxy)

Answer (score 1):

try to send the header

```
 header("Cache-Control: no-transform");
```

(works with german 1&1 provider)

Answer (score 0):

How can we know what is the problem ?

Your path may be valid but are you sure the images are located in the proper folder ?

By the way, your website doesn't show the whole website or only images ?

Try to locate your images in another folder (for example the same as your webpages) and then give it a try.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think it's common. It occures when Django application works on domain sub.domain.com and is moved to domain.com.